# xkill Used On Desktop

Tags: shell, ubuntu, linux-mint, terminal, startup

Mouse accidentally clicked on Desktop while active with an `xkill` terminal command. 
Which makes it completely without use.

Have used `nemo` command which resets everything as long as terminal remains active.

Can Desktop be reset in another style? For a fresh start without hinderances.

Would prefer not to reboot since this happens every blue moon.

Answer (score 0):

If running `nemo` from a terminal works for you until you close the terminal, then run

```
nohup nemo &
```

With [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup), Nemo won't be killed when you exit the terminal.